# How do I get the img src inside a <li><div> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the src of an image from a selected list item.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<li id="player_7">
  <div class="nailthumb-container square-thumb">
    <img src="../photos/files/7/thumb/6c0f1676cdcb1a9a5215db3e12572450.jpeg" />
  </div>
</li>
```

I can currently get the player ID from the selected list element like so:

jQuery

```
$('#myDiv').find("li").click(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('id').substr(7);
});
```

How can I get the img src from a selected list element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `user_id` corresponds to number in player ID, then try:

```
var src = $("#player_" + user_id + " img").prop("src");
```

Otherwise, respectively to the clicked list item:

```
$("#myDiv").find("li").click(function() {
    var src = $("img", this).prop("src");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Get image element using jQuery then read its src property.

```
$('#myDiv').find("li").click(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('id').substr(7);
   var src = $("img", this)[0].src;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you're doing `$("#myDiv").find("li")` when `"$("#myDiv li")` should do just fine? Then, at that point, the following would suffice:

```
$('#myDiv li").click(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('id').substr(7);
    var src = $("img",this).attr('src');
    // ...
});
```

Personally, I'd favor using a split on the ID to get the user_id, (`.attr('id').split('_')[1]`), but seeing as you'd have to modify your code either way if you needed to change your prefix or naming convention, I don't suppose that really matters much. It might affect performance (as split has always seemed to be faster, though I can't remember why), if you had a lot of these to parse at one time, but otherwise, for one-by-one operations, substr should work just fine.